# Keyframe animation issue in IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, css, animation, keyframe

I have css animation that works beautifully in all real browsers, but as expected its not working well in IE10. **It now seems that IE doesn't want to rotate `360deg` properly. Still Looking for possible work around, that wont sacrifice function in real browsers.**

**EDIT** <strike>It seems that ie10 will `translateX` or `rotate(360deg)`, but wont do both at the same time</strike>.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/v7k7f/4/), and the code:

```
@keyframes lightSpeedIn {
0% {
    top: 30px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: translateX(700px) skewX(-50deg) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 0;
}
25% {
    top: 15px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: translateX(0px) skewX(-50deg)rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
}
35% {
    top: 15px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: translateX(-25px) skewX(0deg)rotate(180deg);
    opacity: 1;
}
65% {
    top: -15px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: translateX(0px) skewX(0deg)rotate(360deg);
    opacity: 1;
}
100% {
    top: -15px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: translateX(0px) skewX(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
}
}
.lightSpeedIn {
    -webkit-animation-name: lightSpeedIn;
    -moz-animation-name: lightSpeedIn;
    -o-animation-name: lightSpeedIn;
    animation-name: lightSpeedIn;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
```

Comment: It's not a problem about  miximg

Comment: It's not a problem about  mixing rotate and skew; it's a problem about rotating around 180 deg. If you add a step in 34% with rotate(179deg) you will see that to go from there to 35% 180deg it goes all the way around counterclockwise. I guess that you "may be" could get it right rotating from -180deg to 180deg (and setting a fixed 180deg rotation somewhere else).

Comment: @vals it seems that you may have a point about it not being a mixing problem. For some reason I can get a full 360deg rotation and move it with translateX if I go from 0% straight to 100%. I wish IE would listen to Yoda- "Do or do not there is no try" [IE doesn't suck less](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lD9FAOPBiDk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I managed to make it work.

I have created 3 more steps near the buggy zone:

```
34.98% {
    top: 15px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: translateX(-25px) skewX(0deg)rotate(179deg);
    opacity: 1;
}    
34.985% {
    top: 15px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: translateX(-25px) skewX(0deg)rotate(179deg);
    opacity: 0;
}    
34.99% {
    top: 15px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: translateX(-25px) skewX(0deg)rotate(180deg);
    opacity: 0;
}
35% {
    top: 15px;
    transform-origin: top left;
    transform: translateX(-25px) skewX(0deg)rotate(180deg);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

As you can see the idea is get to almost 180 deg, turn off visibility, get to 180 deg, and turn on visibility. And all this in as few time as posible.

### [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v7k7f/5/)

I have slowed it down so that it is easy to check

About keeping it from spoil other brothers, well, given the IE people ****** decision to unprefix that property (I will leave the * space so that everybody can put the adjective that wants), I guess that you should review that design sometime in the future.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort put in. I miss the good old days when IE just didn't animate. It was easier to deal with IE not showing animations, rather than showing them poorly.